# Else part of an if statement is not running for my PHP code

Tags: javascript, php

I am writing a form page to register farmers in my farmers table. I've written a mysql query to do that and another one to check if the farmer has been registered. When I run it on my localhost, if the query returns true it will proceed but if it return false, the else part won't be executed.

```
$farmer_id = $_REQUEST['frm_id'];
$farmer_name = $_REQUEST['frm_name'];
$password = md5($_REQUEST['pwd']);
$phone_number = $_REQUEST['phone_no'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `farmers` VALUES ('$farmer_id', '$farmer_name', '$password', '$phone_number', '$email')";
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `farmers` WHERE `user_id` = '$farmer_id' OR `phone` = '$phone_number'";
$chck = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
$ros = mysqli_fetch_array($chck);

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
{
  echo
  "<script>
  alert('farmer registered successfully');
  if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
      window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
  }
  </script>";

}
elseif($ros['user_id'] || $ros['phone'])
{
  echo
  "<script>
  alert('Oops, it seems a farmer with that ID or Phone number has already been registered');
  if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
    window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
  }
  </script>";

}
else
{
  echo 
  "<script>
  alert('error');
  if(window.history.replaceState) {
    window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
  }
  </script>";
}
```

I expect when I register a farmer of say ID 1234Jhn twice, the elseif part executes and I get an alert saying 'Oops, it seems a farmer with that ID or Phone number has already been registered' but instead nothing happens and when I try reloading the page the form I get a 'Confirm form resubmission'. Where I could I have gone wrong and what should I do to rectify the mistake.

Comment: Why not check for duplicates _before_ you try to insert a new farmer?

Comment: Actually this works the way I wanted, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your duplicate checking should come before insertion.

```
if($ros['user_id'] || $ros['phone'])
{
    echo
    "<script>
    alert('Oops, it seems a farmer with that ID or Phone number has already been registered');
    if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
        window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
    }
    </script>";
}
elseif(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
{
  echo
  "<script>
  alert('farmer registered successfully');
  if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
      window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
  }
  </script>";

}
else
{
  echo 
  "<script>
  alert('error');
  if(window.history.replaceState) {
    window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
  }
  </script>";
}
```

Comment: This one worked, thanks.

Comment: @Maxswell If this answer solved your problem, please _accept_ it if you can, so it is marked as resolved